# Cannot insert text into a message field on messenger.com

Tags: javascript, html, insert

This is not one of those "how to insert text in input" questions. I've checked them all.

So I need to insert some text on page load into the message field on `message.com`.

The problem is that while the input is empty, it is just a `<br data-text="true">` element. Then if you type something in, it changes to `<span data-text="true"></span>`. React does that.

I can add text to this span's `innerHTML` or `textContent` but in order for the tag to appear, I still need to type one letter manually into the message field. If i try to change `innerHtml` or `textContent` on `br` element nothing happens.

I tried `selection` and `range`:

```
let selection = window.getSelection();
let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
let node = document.createTextNode(text)
range.insertNode(node);`
```

it kinda works, in a way that I just insert a new `textnode`, but I cannot send that text, so it is useless. 
I spent all day on this and now I'm not even sure if it is possible.

Comment: Need more info. Can you post the HTML from the site? I tried going there to check, but I am not willing to make an account to look.

Comment: have updated the description. messenger.com is a facebook's app for messaging, you can log in there with your facebook account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so for everyone who stumbles upon something similar, when you just can't change the DOM directly, as all the answers to similar problems suggest, here is my solution. It is SO simple.
You could use `clipboard API`. First you add the text to the clipboard with:
`navigator.clipboard.writeText('text')`
 It returns a promise in case you need it. 
Then you paste the text at cursor position with `document.execCommand('paste');`
And that's it! In my case, as this was a part of my chrome extension, i also needed to put in the `permissions` key in `manifest.json` the following permissions: `"clipboardRead", "clipboardWrite"`
Good luck!
P.S. As i see tt is a new feature and is not available in IE and Safary.